# Yii2 button with external link

Tags: url, button, yii2

I'm using Yii 2.0.15 and have trouble with getting an external link from database to a button.

In the database I have a field `url` as a string:

```
$url = $db->url // string: https:://the-url-from-database.org
```

In the view I create the button like this:

```
echo Html::a($title, $url, ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
```

And the link that's set is:

```
https://frontend.myapp.local/https:://the-url-from-database.org
```

When I write the same in plain text like this:

```
Html::a('Button Title', "https:://the-url-from-database.org", ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
```

I get:

```
https:://the-url-from-database.org
```

Strange, I don't understand this behavior. Any tipps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL from database is incorrect. You have doubled colon after protocol, so it is not treated as absolute URL, but as relative URL. It should be:

```
https://the-url-from-database.org
```

instead of

```
https:://the-url-from-database.org
```

Comment: thanks a lot, saved my day! i think i should get more sleep ;-)